# Check if a user has permission to access a controller action (before accessing it)

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an action, `TopSecret()`, which has a security policy applied to it:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Level2SecurityClearance")]
public IActionResult TopSecret()
```

I could check the user meets the requirements of the policy by doing this (`authorizationService` is of type `IAuthorizationService`)

```
bool isAuthorised = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "Level2SecurityClearance");
```

This action may have a different policy applied at some point in the future and I don't want to have to find all the places I generate links to it and update the code. Is it possible to test if a user can access a specific action?

Maybe something like this:

```
// Not a real method!!!
bool isAuthorised = authorizationService.IsAuthorisedForAction(User, "TopSecret", "SecretController");
```

Comment: https :// channel9. msdn. com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/ASPNET-Core-Authorization-with-Barry-Dorrans Check out this video. It is specifically focused on auth for asp.net core, and he spells Authorised the same as you. @Blowdart

Comment: Thanks @PatrickMcvay, I've already watched both his videos. Unfortunately he doesn't address my question in them - and we both spell Authorise correctly because we're both British ;)

Comment: public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        } Have you tried something like this and then inject your auth stuff there. By the way that is overriding the controller

Answer (score 2):

You should look into developing Requirements

Here's an example for you using your criteria:

note: I'm assuming you're using Identity3 and your User has claims with the access

In a new class called Level2SecurityClearanceRequirement

```cs
public class Level2SecurityClearanceRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<Level2SecurityClearanceRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, Level2SecurityClearanceRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim("TopSecret","yes")
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

In your controller method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> BlahBlah() {
    if (!await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, nameof(PolicyName.Level2SecurityClearance), new Level2SecurityClearanceRequirement()))
        return new ChallengeResult();
}
```

note that I'm using nameof() here so that you don't have any magic strings and all your resources are centralized.

In this case I have an enum:

```cs
public enum PolicyName {
    Level2SecurityClearance
}
```

in your startup.cs:

in the ConfigureServices method

add the following:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>{
    options.AddPolicy(nameof(PolicyName.Level2SecurityClearance), policy => { policy.AddRequirements(new Level2SecurityClearanceRequirement()); });
});
```

you can then use this requirement whereever you please and the checks are done in the requirement itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Tested in **ASP.NET Core 1.1**

```
//somewhere in view
@if (await Url.HasAccess(urlActionContext))
{
    <p>You have access</p>
}
```

Extension method

```
public static async Task<bool> HasAccess(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, UrlActionContext urlActionContext, string httpMethod = "GET" )
{

    var httpContext = urlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext;

    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(urlActionContext.Values);
    routeValues["action"] = urlActionContext.Action;
    routeValues["controller"] = urlActionContext.Controller;          

    var path = urlHelper.Action(urlActionContext);

    var features = new FeatureCollection();
    features.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(new HttpRequestFeature()
    {
        Method = httpMethod, 
        Path = path,

    });

    var ctx = new DefaultHttpContext(features);      

    var routeContext = new RouteContext(ctx);

    foreach (var entry in routeValues)
    {
        routeContext.RouteData.Values.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }

    var actionSelector = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionSelector>();

    var provider = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();       
    var actionDescriptors = actionSelector.SelectCandidates(routeContext);

    var actionDescriptor = actionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(routeContext, actionDescriptors);

    var authService = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();

    //You need to implement your own AuthorizationHandler that 
    //checks the actionDescriptor. It will be in AuthorizationHandlerContext.Resource. 
    //In my case, I have custom Authorize attribute applied to the 
    //controller action and this attribute is available 
    //in actionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors

    var ok = await authService.AuthorizeAsync(httpContext.User, actionDescriptor, "YOUR_POLICY"); 

    return ok;

}
```